# How to generate a table in Haddock documentation

Tags: haskell, haddock

I am writing some documentation with Haddock, and I need to put a multi-column table with some values in it. How can I do it with Haddock? I cannot find info about it. Embedding some html as alternative looks no possible too.

Comment: I don't think there is any proper support for tables. You may have to make do with an image file.

Comment: There is now mathjax support in haddock so it may be possible to create a table using e.g. \begin{matrix} and \mathrm{...} - a bit rubbish but possibly better than an image file. Alternatively, you could add table support to haddock - the code is not difficult to modify but you'd have to worry about output formats other than html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haddock bundled with GHC 8.4 or newer (Haddock version >= 2.18.2) supports tables. As per [the pull request where this was added](https://github.com/haskell/haddock/pull/718), the syntax is based on [RST Grid tables](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#grid-tables).

## Sample use:

```
module Sample where

-- | A table:
--
-- +------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
-- | Header row, column 1   | Header 2   | Header 3 | Header 4 |
-- | (header rows optional) |            |          |          |
-- +========================+============+==========+==========+
-- | body row 1, column 1   | column 2   | column 3 | column 4 |
-- +------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
-- | body row 2             | Cells may span columns.          |
-- +------------------------+------------+---------------------+
-- | body row 3             | Cells may  | \[                  |
-- +------------------------+ span rows. | f(n) = \sum_{i=1}   |
-- | body row 4             |            | \]                  |
-- +------------------------+------------+---------------------+
sample :: ()
sample = ()
```

Turns into

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Haddock "markup"](https://github.com/haskell/haddock/blob/haddock-2.17.3-release/haddock-library/src/Documentation/Haddock/Types.hs#L56-L80) doesn't currently support tables, see also [Haddock User Guide - Chapter 3. Documentation and Markup](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html). There is an [open issue](https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/530) to add support for simple tables.